# How to show password only on click and hold of eye?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a password field and i want to show the password **when someone click on the eye icon** and when the leave the mouse click i want to mask the password again. How to do that?

I found the below code, but in this the event is on hover I need on click and hold
.

```js
$('.icon').hover(function () {
   $('.password').attr('type', 'text'); 
}, function () {
   $('.password').attr('type', 'password'); 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="password" class="password" type="password" />
<div class="fa fa-eye icon"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('.icon').mousedown(function () {
   $('.password').attr('type', 'text'); 
});

$('.icon').on('mouseup mouseleave', function () {
   $('.password').attr('type', 'password'); 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="password" class="password" type="password" />
<div class="fa fa-eye icon"></div>
```

Comment: I am facing one problem with this approach. If the user clicks the eye icon - the password will be visible. If he drags the mouse outside the eye icon and then releases the click, then the password still remains visible. How to address this?

Comment: @manjuv I edited my answer with mouseup and mouseleave.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.icon').click(function () {
   if ($('.password').attr('type') == 'text') {
      $('.password').attr('type', 'password');
   } else {
      $('.password').attr('type', 'text');
   }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="password" class="password" type="password" />
<div class="fa fa-eye icon"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested!

```js
 $('.icon').click(function () {
    $('.password').attr('type', 'text');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('.password').attr('type', 'password');
    }, 200); 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="password" class="password" type="password" />
<div class="fa fa-eye icon"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery)

```
$('.icon').hover(function () {
   $('.password').attr('type', 'text'); 
}, function () {
   $('.password').attr('type', 'password'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you can add the eye button for show and hide the password, also the eye button change after change status (show password/hide password).

```js
$('.icon').click(function () {
   if ($('#my-password').attr('type') == 'text') {
      $('#my-password').attr('type', 'password');
      $('#show-password').removeClass('fa-eye-slash').addClass('fa-eye');
   } else {
      $('#my-password').attr('type', 'text');
      $('#show-password').removeClass('fa-eye').addClass('fa-eye-slash');
   }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="password" id="my-password" type="password" />
<div class="fa fa-eye icon" id="show-password"></div>
```

I used the ID attribute for select password input and eye button.